# Can we neglect matrices with smaller eigenvalues in comparison to ones with larger eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Can two matrices be compared as being "small" and "large"? For example, consider  matrix $X=X(t)$  as a function of parameter $t$ (say for time), such that
\begin{equation}
\frac{d X}{dt} = YX^2 + Z
\end{equation}
for some constant matrices $Y$ and $Z$. Under what conditions can one neglect matrix $Z$ in this equation?

Comment: What does "neglect" mean?

Comment: I borrowed the terminology from real numbers where you can "neglect" (or forget) 1 in comparison to one million.